# Make persistent CSS and JS in Yii2 Advanced Template

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii2-advanced-app, persistent

I've been developed a project using Yii2 framework, and I've modifid the CSS and JS from `backend\web\assets\12qwer34`. But when I clone the project into new directory project, the new one project didn't use the same CSS and JS from `backend\web\assets\12qwer34`, it's uses CSS and JS from another directory.

Any one knows how to make the CSS and JS become persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files under directory `backend\web\assets` are generated from original .css files.

In `backend\assets\` you have `AppAsset.php` file where you can add your custom css files by setting property:

```
public $css = ['styles/yourstyles.css'];
```

And then add a file called `yourstyles.css` in `backend\web\styles\`.